# How to upload a HTML file on server so that it displays like a webpage?

Tags: html, server

The question is about uploading a file to a web server which could be accessed from a domain address and is not specific to WordPress only.

My server runs WordPress, so there's a japanaddicts.org directory in the root space. Now, I created a sub-domain through my hosting provider. The address is paperwork.japanaddicts.org

I checked through FTP, and saw that a directory named the same has been created. When I open it, then the htaccess folder, and add my paperwork.html file (with an embedded stylesheet), it doesn't work properly.

When I open paperwork.japanaddicts.org, it opens a directory listing, which is fine for a rudimentary start. But after opening the paperwork file, paperwork.japanaddicts.org/paperwork, it opens the html file, instead of parsing the code within.

Please advise on how to make that page view as a webpage with all the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the real FQDN; loading the actual page tells me right away what the issue is.

The URL http://paperwork.japanaddicts.org/paperwork is not actually serving index.html from a directory, it is serving a file in the document root called `paperwork`. Since there is no file extension for the server to determine MIME type, it is being served as `text/plain`. You can verify this by going to http://paperwork.japanaddicts.org/paperwork/index.html.

You can use various server configuration settings to serve the file at the URI of your choice, or change the filename to `paperwork.html`. You can even add `paperwork` to the web server's MIME types. But the simplest solution is to create a directory called `paperwork`, put your HTML file inside it, and rename the file to `index.html`. Then you can browse to the first URL above as mentioned in the question.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! That worked, I renamed it to index.html. Now I remember that yeah, the first thing a browser looks for is a index database. Thanks, and I don't think I'm intelligent enough to comprehend the meaning of MIME types, but maybe later I'll do that.